# How to reference built assets in the config for Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, symfony4, sonata-admin, webpack-encore

I have an application developed with Symfony 4, using SonataAdminBundle and Webpack Encore.

For the admin I use extra JS and CSS. The source files are:

```
- assets
  - css
    app.css
  - js
    app.js
```

After I run `yarn encore dev` the following files are bumped into `public\build\`:

```
app.css
app.js
runtime.js
```

In the `config` for `sonata_admin` (`config/packages/sonata_admin.yaml`) I reference them like this:

```
sonata_admin:
    extra_stylesheets:
        - build/app.css
    extra_javascripts:
        - build/runtime.js
        - build/app.js
```

The problem is when I want to deploy the app I have to run `yarn encore prod`, and then the filenames of the assets change, something like `app.ea54ac26.js`, where the middle part is dynamically generated.

In a Twig template I can use for example:

```
{{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
```

to load all built JS files.

What is the proper way to reference these files in the config file for Sonata Admin?

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a way to use Webpack compiled files in config. I guess the `extra_stylesheets` and `extra_javascripts` might be for static named scripts.

The way I figured this out (for a Symfony 4 project using Sonata Admin 3.51.0) was to copy `vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/src/Resources/views/standard_layout.html.twig` to `templates/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/standard_layout.html.twig` then add the following in the newly copied file:

```
{% block stylesheets %}

    [ORIGINAL CONTENT]

    {# Admin Webpack Encore generated custom stylesheets #}
    {{ encore_entry_link_tags('admin') }}

{% endblock %}

[...]

{% block javascripts %}

    [ORIGINAL CONTENT]

    {# Admin Webpack Encore generated custom javascript #}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('admin') }}

{% endblock %}
```

Then edited `webpack.config.js`

```
Encore
    [...]
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .addEntry('admin', './assets/js/admin.js')
    [...]
```

Created `assets/js/admin.js` with the following content:

```
require('../css/admin.scss');

// add other required JS libs here

// add custom JS here or require it from external files just as you do with libs

console.log('it works');
```

Created `assets/css/admin.scss` with the following content:

```
.skin-black {
    .main-header > {
        .logo {
            background-color: red;
            color: white;
    }
}
```

Now you need to clear Symfony's cache `php bin/console cache:clear` in order to notice the new template and you should be done. When accessing the admin section you should see the message `it works` logged in the browser's console the admin logo's background should be red (assuming you use SCSS in your project).

If you are not using SCSS in your project, you can use the `.css` file extension and some CSS instead.

It might not be the best solution out there, but it definitely works.

Good luck fighting the `jQuery` version now :)